# Programmed IO vs interrupt for devices

Tags: interrupts, cpu, io

Although I can understand the difference between programmed IO (PIO) and interrupt (INT) transfers, still there is something vague.

In PIO, the processor repeatedly checks READY pin to see if the device is ready. However, in interrupt mode, the processor checks the INT pin at the end of the instruction cycle.

My question is, in interrupt mode, the processor still has to repeatedly checks the INT pin. I know that in this mode, the external device send the interrupt signal, but how processor becomes aware of that interrupt? The processor has to repeatedly check the INT pin on every cycle (or instruction cycle). Doesn't it?

References:

{1} http://www.louiewong.com/archives/137

{2} https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-programmed-driven-I-O-and-interrupt-driven-I-O-What-is-one-advantage-and-one-disadvantage-of-each

{3} http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/Chapter3.ppt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PIO mode the processor is executing instructions that check the IO. That means it's not executing other instructions during that time.

In IRQ mode the check is performed by the same part of the hardware that normally increments the instruction pointer, or handles jumps. The check itself doesn't "cost" anything other than a tiny bit of processor chip area.

Comment: So, do you have any example for them? What I understood is that they both do the same thing but the latter has lower cost. That means, at the end of the day, CPU has to periodically check to see if device has something new for it, but in interrupt mode, the CPU only checks some status bits

Comment: Instead of repeatedly executing software instructions to check the device, it repeatedly checks pins

Comment: The interrupt recognition and calling of the Interrupt Service Routine is done entirely in hardware - the main program doesn't have to check any status bits for the interrupt to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with PIO the CPU has to periodically execute instructions which read the READY pin and decide what to do about it, whereas in interrupt mode the CPU just keeps executing the main code and is 'interrupted' by extra hardware which is monitoring the INT pin.

Typically the hardware interrupt saves the current PC on the stack and then jams the interrupt vector address into it, causing the CPU to jump to the interrupt handler code. This may only take a few cycles, but since the main program is not aware that it has happened the interrupt handler must *also* save and restore any registers that it changes. As a result the time required to process an interrupt may be much longer than using PIO.

Comment: So the concept is to check related IO pins via software codes (PIO) or hardware circuits (IRQ). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to look at a processor architecture. Look up Mips pipeline with hazards. It can get a little complex, but what is being pointed out is that the PC(program clock) of processors is in itself the pointer. When something like an interrupt happens, it goes to the hazard unit, which also acts as the interrupt vector table. This vector table takes care of all the mapping and controls a few pieces of the processor to stall, jump, branch (ISR things). In many cases, it says to do something in Kernal mode, or syscall as MIPS calls it. This means a software interrupt.

In the case of PIO, everytime you want to check a pin, you must process instructions to point to that pin, call a peripheral to do that, report back, and check the results with another instruction.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I am, six years later, stumbling into this.

Programmed I/O is I/O that is performed by the CPU using program instructions. That’s all that means. Interrupts are a separate concept that can be applied to programmed I/O to make it more efficient.

Programmed I/O can be controlled by monitoring a status signal, sampled by the program itself. This is called *polling*, a simple, if somewhat inefficient way to manage I/O flow control.

*Interrupt* feeds a signal to the CPU, such that when the signal fires it causes the program to branch to a routine to service a task, such as completing an I/O transfer. There’s special hardware to do this, the *interrupt controller*, that processes the signal and tells  the CPU where to go (via the *interrupt vector*) to get further instructions.

Using interrupts relieves the CPU of the burden of polling the signal, and allows concurrency of I/O and other processing. The CPU doesn’t have to wait around in a polling loop, it can branch to another task instead. This greatly improves system response.

Nevertheless, for programmed I/O, the CPU is still responsible for moving the data, whether polling or interrupt is used.