# How does programmed IO vs interrupt driven IO work?

Tags: interrupts, cpu, io

I know how programmed IO and interrupt driven IO work but I am confused if I am right about their working or not:

This is the flowchart given in this site: https://slideplayer.com/slide/265620/

I used references from this electronics.stackexchange to modify algorithm and flowchart for programmed IO and interrupt driven IO.

[Programmed IO vs interrupt for devices](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204337/programmed-io-vs-interrupt-for-devices)

[image]

Here is what I have thought of. Tell me where I am wrong or if I am right.

This is my programmed IO:

[image]

This is my interrupt driven IO:

[image]

My definition:

1. Programmed IO:

Here the CPU periodically executes instructions which read the READY pin

2. Interrupt driven IO:

Here the CPU checks interrupt at the end of each instruction cycle whereas IO device sends interrupt.

Where is my concept wrong - or am I right?

According to my teacher and stackexchange answers of the past, I seem right. But I have no surity that I am right. That is why I am asking here. Both looks very similar to me and seem to work as well.

Note: Ignore some flowchart conventions, like not putting diamond box in Ready etc.

Comment: *according to flowchart I have confusions* - you haven't explained what your confusion is. Nobody here is telepathic.

Comment: My confusion is does this work? Is this flowchart I made valid? I don't know how do I judge this flowchart. So asking here.

Comment: Surely, you can make a comparison with the published flow chart in your question. How hard is that to do?

Comment: It looks fine to me, but I am not confident about that so asking here.

Comment: This is an EE site so, asking to check whether one flowchart is about the same as another is really down to you. Personally speaking I think **you** need to justify the differences between the published information and what you have produced.

Comment: Ok please stop downvoting me, I will analyze and edit the post.

Comment: There's one significant difference between the published flow charts and your own. As this looks like a homework question I will not go into detail. It would help if you could formulate a clear and unambiguous question and not let us guess.

Comment: @StarCat I took a look at it I don't see any differences between these 2 versions of flowchart. Only difference is i am not reading status but doing that by checking ready pin and in another case i am checking int pin. Stackexchange told me the same so I made like that.

Comment: In cases where I/O is a module integrated into a microcontroller chip, what you describe as **ready pin** would not be a "pin", but would be a bit in a status register. That status register might be mapped into RAM, or into I/O address space, depending on the particular microcontroller. For *interrupts*, a RAM or I/O - mapped flag bit *could* be available...so you can determine **who** caused the interrupt (where many modules require interrupt service). You *might* be required to reset this flag...this would alter the flowchart.

Comment: Just a note: the technical English programming term is "polled I/O", not "programmed IO".  "Polled" because -- well, hard to explain.  It used to mean "head" (still does in some cattle-farming terminology), it came to mean "voting" or "asking opinions" because "counting heads".  It's probably in the "I'll take a poll!" sense that it's used.

Answer (score 7):

The terminology is kind of messed up. *Programmed I/O* means I/O that is performed by the CPU directly under program control, as opposed to *Direct Memory Access*, or DMA, where dedicated hardware is performing the I/O.

What’s actually being compared here is *polling* vs. *interrupt* control of an I/O process. In polling, the CPU program samples a status signal periodically and takes action in response to its state. With interrupt, the status pin state change causes the CPU execution to branch to an *interrupt service routine*, which in turn takes care of the I/O.

Let me emphasize this point: **the CPU doesn’t ‘check’ for the interrupt at all, let alone after every cycle.** The interrupted program has no direct awareness of the interrupt occurrence. Instead, on sensing the interrupt event, lower level hardware intervenes and makes the program counter switch over to the interrupt service routine, much like reset forces the PC to branch to zero, the reset vector.

The advantages of using interrupts are a much reduced CPU overhead and shorter response time for asynchronous events. Interrupts also simplify *concurrency* of I/O with other processes: the CPU is free to switch to another task rather than sitting in a polling loop waiting for something to happen.

Polling, on the other hand, is easier to understand and debug, at least in the beginning. Many developers will start with polling then optimize later using interrupts.

Nevertheless, for the example shown, both are actually programmed I/O. Maybe gently remind your instructor of this.

Further reading about interrupts and programmed I/O:  http://www.simply embedded.org/tutorials/interrupt-free-ring-buffer/

Comment: >Nevertheless, for the example shown, both are actually programmed I/O. Maybe gently remind your instructor of this.

Oh no. I was actually sceptical about that so I made a new flowchart. I will avoid writing this flowchart unless I got asked to write about it. I understand about Interrupts etc I was just confused about this flowchart.. But this flowchart is in every website in internet, I am surprised that it is wrong..

Comment: The flowchart is simplistic at best. It’s not exactly wrong, but the terminology is a bit mangled. Programmed I/O and interrupts are isolated concepts, not alternative approaches. They really mean ‘polling’.

Comment: Oh, and the other Q you linked to? The answer is… kinda off target.

Comment: >They really mean ‘polling’. 

Oh really? That was what I was thinking when i heard that after every instruction cycle, interrupt is checked by microprocessor(some area of microprocessor). Thanks for the clarification. They both indeed look similar. and the flowchart too looks similar. Except that arrow part.

Comment: The CPU doesn’t ‘check’ for an interrupt. The interrupt causes the CPU program counter to change (branch) to the beginning of the interrupt service routine (the interrupt vector).

Comment: it actually does after the end of each instruction cycle. read instruction cycle diagram or sth. I also used to think like you later I learnt abou this.

Comment: The CPU has no direct knowledge of the interrupt *at the program level*. The program stream doesn’t ‘check’ anything - that would defeat the purpose of the interrupt. The details of processing the interrupt signal and taking the branch are lower-level actions, that if implemented correctly, are transparent to the CPU and the program it’s running. The interrupt could be implemented by microinstructions, a finite state machine, or direct logic to compute the next program counter. It doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems here.

First is *semantics*. The "CPU periodically executes instructions which read the READY pin" and "Read status of IO module" are different things. I don't know what you mean under "READY pin", but IO status is usually a bit (or several bits) in some register related to IO operations.

The "CPU checks interrupt at the end of each instruction cycle" is technically correct. However the way you phrased these two statements leaves an impression that these are similar processes ("looks very similar to me"). In reality they are completely different.

When CPU executes instructions to read IO status those instructions are part of your program. And when the check is complete other instructions define what to do next. So, **your program controls the check and the outcome**.

In contrast, when CPU checks interrupt, this is *hardwired functionality of the processor*, no instructions are executed. Your program only tells CPU where to go when the condition is met, and that is done way before it actually happens. So, **the CPU does the check and the only possible outcome is either do nothing or pause whatever it was doing and jump to the predefined address in your program.**

Second problem is *logic*. The flow chart on the right is **completely wrong**. In fact, your hand-drawn chart is much closer to reality!

Note, that "do something else" and "next instruction" (I marked them on the chart below) refer to something in the main code. However "interrupt" arrow indicates an entry from that hardwired check mentioned above. The CPU *interrupted* whatever it was doing and jumped to the interrupt handling code. But when this handling is done, it MUST return exactly to where it was before. It cannot continue along either of those two main pathways. This return arrow is missing on the chart.

[image]

In your hand-drawn chart, "write word" box must be followed by the check for the end of the operation, then (only if not done) by another request to IO, and then (mandatory) by the arrow "return from interrupt". Note, that this makes interrupt handling code **separate** from the main program body, which is clearly seen on your picture but totally messed up in the "educational" flow chart.

Now, just to make things clear, here are some notes on interrupt handling.

Most important is that there are many different interrupts, each associated with specific condition. So, when interrupt is configured it usually tracks exactly what you need. For example not "something happened with IO module", but "data received" or "transmit failed". This way you do not have to check for IO status in program, you *already know* what is going on by the fact that your specific interrupt handler is running.

Another thing is that there are different interrupt priorities, which means when interrupt happens the CPU is not necessarily running main code, it can be executing another interrupt handler with lower priority. So, when your code is done the CPU continues to handle that lower interrupt, and only when that is also done it will return to the main program (unless, of course, some other interrupt was triggered in the meantime).

Third, especially in the case of IO operations, the interrupts are often used in combination with DMA. Which means, the IO hardware automatically places data into (or reads from) specified memory locations. So, you do not need those "read word" and "write word" blocks, by the time interrupt happened the data is already where it is supposed to be.

Having said that, the interrupts are extremely flexible. For example, you can setup GPIO interrupts to trigger on level change. Then your program will be reading incoming data bit by bit. Very inefficient, but doable and sometimes unavoidable for dealing with exotic protocols. Or you can setup UART interrupts to trigger when entire byte arrives or error detected. In this case your handlers will be called less frequently, giving CPU more time to process main code. Then, as mentioned above, you can setup one of the supported IO protocol modules and DMA to trigger interrupt only when transmission complete. In this case large data packets can be received without any program involvement.

Finally, there are many different interrupt handling patterns. While it is certainly possible to do many things in the interrupt handlers, you should always consider whether it is really necessary and what are the timing requirements. Use interrupts only for low latency operations and independent parallel processes. For example, if your main program requires some data from IO and it cannot proceed without it, what is the point of using interrupts to read that data? You have to stop main code anyway! Might as well use blocking call to do the input.

Here is an example of a pattern that allows main code to do something else while IO module receives chunks of data and interrupt handler collects those chunks for later use.

[image]

Please note, that all of the above is a simplified version. In addition to the CPU and MCU hardware differences, things are getting even more complicated when some kind of OS is involved. I hope this at least addressed the primary sources of the confusion.